# Auto-Generating ID For Many-To-Many Entities for Linking Table in JPA

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, sequence

My problem is that when I insert an entity in a many-to-many relationship, I can't get an ID to get auto-generated in the linking table.

I have a bi-directional many-to-many relationship between entities Foo and Bar. The linking table called FOO_BAR has FOO_BAR_ID, FOO_ID, and BAR_ID, the first one being the PK on the table. It links the FOO and BAR tables which also have their own PK's, FOO_ID and BAR_ID. These two extend from a common base class which has the @Id with the sequence generator.

```
public abstract class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =  "generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "some_sequence")
    protected Long id;
    //...getters/setters
}
```

The entity Foo is in the FOO table and has its PK named FOO_ID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "FOO_ID"))
public class Foo extends ParentEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "FOO_BAR",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID"))
    protected Set<Bar> bars;
    //...getters/setters
}
```

This entity Bar is the BAR table with its own PK of BAR_ID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "BAR_ID"))
public class Bar extends ParentEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bars", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    protected Set<Foo> foos;
    //...getters/setters
}
```

The linking table has FOO_ID, BAR_ID, and its own PK called FOO_BAR_ID.

The problem is that when I try and insert a new Foo, an ID isn't getting inserted for the PK in the FOO_BAR linking table. The other two IDs look like they would be inserted just fine.

When I persist using the following:

```
@Transactional
public void baz() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Bar bar = entityManager.find(barId);
    foo.setBars(new HashSet<Bar>());
    foo.getBars().add(bar);
    entityManager.persist(foo);
    //also tried .merge just for giggles
}
```

On persist is where the error happens. Looking at the SQL log this is what gets output:

```
DEBUG: org.hibernate.SQL - select some_sequence.nextval from dual
DEBUG: org.hibernate.SQL - insert into FOO (FOO_ID, NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG: org.hibernate.SQL - insert into FOO_BAR (FOO_ID, BAR_ID) values (?, ?)
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MY_SCHEMA"."FOO_BAR"."FOO_BAR_ID")
```

This makes sense based on the SQL getting executed but I'm not sure how to get the linking table's PK to get generated.

As I'm sure many of you can appreciate, due to client restrictions this is just the way it has to be but I can't figure out if this is just impossible or if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two main options you have are:

1) Change the join table so it only has a `FOO_ID` and a `BAR_ID` and the primary key is the combination of both these fields,

or

2) If you want the join table to contain more than just a `FOO_ID` and a `BAR_ID`, then you need to define the join table as a separate Entity class (`FooBar`). Then both `Foo` and `Bar` will have one-to-many associations to `FooBar`.

Comment: We ended up just making another entity for the linking table. I wish there was a more elegant solution but this will do.